# Youtube API error in Oreo 8.1 while initializing the YouTube player

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

Youtube API is working perfectly below N version but with 8.1 Oreo it will this error

```
10-30 10:36:17.033 12166-12166/com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague, PID: 12166
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague/com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague.Service_Info_Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
    at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1464)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1609)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1557)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:684)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source:69)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source:67)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity$a.a(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.initialize(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague.Service_Info_Activity.initView(Service_Info_Activity.java:92)
    at com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague.Service_Info_Activity.onCreate(Service_Info_Activity.java:57)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2734)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1592) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

i am using lettest [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) for that still it is gives this error, here is my code for initializing the youtube player.

```
 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>






 mYoutubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    mYoutubeView.initialize("AIzaSyCJTK0EL5EM7esPnxf8iFzW-__cvq5asf8", this);
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.loadVideo(Youtube_Link); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhWaJi1Hsfo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(WebConstants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return mYoutubeView;
    }
```

the problem with only oreo 8.1 i am using latest version on of youtube application, how to solve this error.

```
  [1]: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/
```

Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.name.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.name.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Service_Info_Activity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oceanleaguewebcranks.app.oceanleague"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/mipmap/logo'] } }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'

    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'

//    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip')
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your manifest file and app level gradle please?

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån Manifest and Gradle added please check

Comment: Have you added this line: implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip') or it automatically was added by AS?

Comment: no i am added that line

Comment: Remove it and try..

Comment: will that line is for latest  YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi

Comment: Yeah but you have already added it in your lib folder so no need to add in gradle again.

Comment: @Ümañgßürmån after changing library solved my problem, thank you

Comment: Ok Good, What library you changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(WebConstants.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);


@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to initialize.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    if(null== player) return;

    // Start buffering
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.loadVideo(Youtube_Link);
    }

    // Add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override public void onAdStarted() { }
        @Override public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) { }
        @Override public void onLoaded(String arg0) { }
        @Override public void onLoading() { }
        @Override public void onVideoEnded() { }
        @Override public void onVideoStarted() { }
    });


    player.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
        @Override public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) { }
        @Override public void onPaused() { }
        @Override public void onPlaying() { }
        @Override public void onSeekTo(int arg0) { }
        @Override public void onStopped() { }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is 1.2.2??

Comment: this is a version of api please visite https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Comment: Manish, then what was the issue?

Comment: the developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads downloded library is use less, i download new library form github

Comment: @ManishAhire so where the link to the newest version?